# Doctrine build-all-reload doesn't work as well

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, command-line-interface

I have a strange problem with doctrine 1.2 and the CLI command build-all-reload. I have created the db and its tables and then I have executed the CLI command ./doctrine dump_data.

Then I have rebuild all using the ./doctrine build-all-reload but some indexes imported are not present in the data.yml, they are different.

This is the data.yml file:

```
Languages:
  Languages_1:
    language: Italiano
    locale: it_IT
    base: false
    active: true
  Languages_2:
    language: English
    locale: en_EN
    base: true
    active: true

CMSPages:
  CMSPages_1:
    title: Company
    body: "<h2>Company</h2>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non  tortor ipsum, sit amet ultricies leo. Aenean scelerisque scelerisque  ultricies. Duis tincidunt, arcu in pulvinar convallis, ipsum arcu  pharetra massa, sit amet congue justo enim id enim. Donec est erat,  tempor at consectetur nec, tempor in arcu. Vestibulum a elit libero, at  lacinia sem. Donec eros felis, tincidunt sed aliquet ut, ultricies sed  orci. Proin elementum facilisis augue a vulputate. Vestibulum consequat,  ligula eget ultricies dictum, justo enim pellentesque nibh, eu laoreet  massa lorem ac orci.</p>\r\n<p>Mauris vehicula ligula non nisl gravida ornare. Mauris enim felis,  adipiscing vel consequat vitae, vulputate vitae nunc. Vivamus viverra  sem vel ligula lobortis eget pellentesque mauris luctus. Class aptent  taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos  himenaeos. Integer venenatis odio a nulla ornare sit amet molestie justo  euismod. Proin quis diam nec leo condimentum ultrices. Ut metus erat,  consectetur eu tempor et, consequat id eros. Mauris tincidunt mollis  arcu, eget ullamcorper dolor dapibus non. Pellentesque accumsan  ultricies arcu sagittis consectetur. Suspendisse auctor ullamcorper  rhoncus. Nulla neque elit, pellentesque et gravida et, lobortis in  metus. Mauris eu felis eros, et vulputate nisl. Curabitur tincidunt  adipiscing metus in porta. Phasellus faucibus, eros et aliquet  fermentum, ligula neque dapibus diam, et congue felis massa sed velit.  Sed accumsan feugiat neque at porta. Donec at laoreet justo.</p>"
    keywords: ''
    blocks: ''
    publishedat: '2011-02-13 12:29:11'
    layout: 2columns-right
    var: company
    showinmenu: true
    showonrss: true
    active: true
    parent_id: '0'
  CMSPages_2:
    title: Homepage
    body: "<div class=\"body-content-homepage\">\r\n     \r\n     <div class=\"leftside\">\r\n          <h2>Homepage</h2>\r\n          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>\r\n          <p>{block name=\"twitter\"}</p>\r\n     </div>\r\n\r\n     <div class=\"rightside\">\r\n          <h3>Wiki Help</h3>\r\n          {module name=\"wiki\" class=\"Shineisp_Custom_Wikilist\" method=\"Show\" }\r\n          {block name=\"contacts\"}\r\n          {block name=\"callouts\"}\r\n     </div>\r\n\r\n</div>"
    keywords: ''
    blocks: ''
    publishedat: '2011-05-20 20:06:56'
    layout: homepage
    var: homepage
    showinmenu: false
    showonrss: false
    active: false
    parent_id: '0'

CMSPagesData:
  CMSPagesData_17:
    CMSPages: CMSPages_1
    Languages: Languages_1
  CMSPagesData_18:
    CMSPages: CMSPages_1
    Languages: Languages_2
  CMSPagesData_45:
    CMSPages: CMSPages_2
    Languages: Languages_1
  CMSPagesData_46:
    CMSPages: CMSPages_2
    Languages: Languages_2
```

This is the schema.yml:

```
CMSPagesData:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: cms_pages_data
  columns:
    page_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: false 
    language_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: false       
  relations:
    Languages:
      local: language_id
      foreign: language_id
      type: one
      onDelete: CASCADE 
    CMSPages:
      local: page_id
      foreign: page_id
      type: one
      onDelete: CASCADE 

CMSPages:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: cms_pages
  columns:
    page_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    title:
      type: string(250)
      notnull: true      
    body:
      type: text()
      notnull: true  
    keywords:
      type: string(250)
    blocks:
      type: text()      
    publishedat:
      type: timestamp
      notnull: true      
    layout:
      type: string(250)
      notnull: true
    var:
      type: string(250)
      notnull: true
    showinmenu:
      type: boolean()
      default: true
      notnull: false
    showonrss:
      type: boolean
      default: '0'      
    active:
      type: boolean
      default: '1'      
    parent_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: false 
      default: 0

Languages:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: languages
  columns:
    language_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    language:
      type: string(250)
      notnull: true
    locale:
      type: string(5)
      notnull: true
    base:
      type: boolean
      default: '0'
    active:
      type: boolean
      default: '1'
```

If I execute the command build-all-reload every CMSPagesData record has four wrong records. Why this happens?

thanks

Comment: I have solved the problem checking the classes wrote before. I have noticed that a method in the class Languages was named getLanguageId and this is used from Doctrine to get the ID when I dump the data with:

    ./doctrine dump-data

I have renamed the getLanguageId method with get_language_id and Doctrine has read the default method get* where * is the field name of the Languages table.

In one sentence: I have overwritten the Doctrine default method.